# form.disable() is not disabling the button inside the form

Tags: html, angular, disable

Here is the HTML code

```
 <form class="example-form" 
  [formGroup]="editCustomerForm" 
  #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editCustomer(f)">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">      
        .....
    </mat-form-field>
  <button
    mat-button color="primary" type="submit"       
    [disabled]="editCustomerForm.invalid">
        EDIT
  </button>
</form>
```

after enabling the form ,everything works as expected
.but after disabling the form ,button again become **active**

Here is my component code

```
export class CustomerEditComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
```

**Initializing**

```
  editCustomerForm: FormGroup;
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  customer$:Observable<Customer>;
  memberships= [
    {name: 'silver'},
    {name: 'Gold'},
    {name: 'Platinum'}
  ];
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private store:Store<fromCustomer.AppState>,
    private customerService:CustomerService,
    private sharedService : SharedService) {

    }
```

> **to Unsubscribe**

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.editCustomerForm = this.fb.group({
      '_name': ['', Validators.required],
      '_phone': ['',Validators.required],
      '_address': ['', Validators.required],
      '_membership': ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.disableForm();

    this.customer$= this.store.select(fromCustomer.getCurrentCustomer)
```

> to enable form from another component

```
    this.sharedService.getClickEvent().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    ).subscribe(
      ()=>{
        this.enableForm();
      }
    )
  }
```

**to disable form**
i dont understand ,whether to give parameters or not

```
  disableForm(){
    this.editCustomerForm.disable();
  }
```

**to enable form**

```
  enableForm(){
    this.editCustomerForm.enable();
  }

}
```

Comment: `[disabled]="editCustomerForm.invalid"` Should not it be `disabled` rather than `invalid`? Does invalid means disabled too?

Comment: I would suggest to look at this [link](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/angular-disable-a-form-while-preserving-state-of-controls-4212d8faad0e). I think it may be very helpful for you situation.

Comment: @ŠimonSlabý I tried ,but it is not working,i dont know why,<fieldset [disabled]="true"></fieldset> is not disabling.